# Trace with respect to a variable

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, trace, matrix-exponential

Supposing a matrix exponential which is a function of two sets of variables, $e^{F(\{x\},\{y\})}$

What would the meaning of $Tr_x(e^{F(\{x\},\{y\})})$ be?

Terribly sorry if this is a dumb question, but I've been searching everywhere and can't find the answer. It showed up in a paper related to QFT which I was reading.

Comment: They might be talking about the [partial trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_trace)

Comment: Is the paper available online?

Comment: Is $F$ linear as a function of each variable?

Comment: F is not necessarily linear in each variable. Here's the paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1410.3831.pdf

The relevant stuff is in section I: Overview of Variational RG (on page 2 and 3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\equiv$ in the equation seems to indicate that equation (2) is meant to be a [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols#Symbols_based_on_equality) of the "trace".  That is, we have (by definition)
$$
\operatorname{Tr}_{v_i} e^{\mathbf H(\{v_i\})} = \sum_{v_1,\dots,v_N = \pm 1} e^{-\mathbf H(\{v_i\})}
$$

Comment: That explains it. I kept expecting it to be some general definition used more broadly, but couldn't for the life of me recall what it meant in math/physics. Thanks so much!